# Running Code with Packages created in Eclipse in Console

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble with running projects that contain packages outside of the Eclipse IDE so I've created a simple example to illustrate the problem.

I've created a project called Toy in Eclipse to represent some sort of simple toy. The layout of the folder generated by Eclipse is:

```
toy
┣ bin
┃ ┗ toy
┃ ┃ ┣ toy_data
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Colour.class
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Phrases.class
┃ ┃ ┗ Toy.class
┣ src
┃ ┗ toy
┃ ┃ ┣ toy_data
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Colour.java
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Phrases.java
┃ ┃ ┗ Toy.java
┣ .classpath
┗ .project
```

*toy.java* imports *toy.toy_data.Colour* and *toy.toy_data.Phrases*, from Eclipse I can successfully run *toy.java*...

however, if I cd into */toy/src/toy* and attempt to run

```
javac Toy.java
```

I get the following as an error:

```
Toy.java:3: error: package toy.toy_data does not exist
import toy.toy_data.Colour;
                ^
Toy.java:4: error: package toy.toy_data does not exist
import toy.toy_data.Phrases;
                ^
Toy.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                Phrases p = new Phrases();
                ^
symbol:   class Phrases
location: class Toy
Toy.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                Phrases p = new Phrases();
                                ^
symbol:   class Phrases
location: class Toy
Toy.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                Colour c = new Colour();
                ^
symbol:   class Colour
location: class Toy
Toy.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                Colour c = new Colour();
                            ^
symbol:   class Colour
location: class Toy
6 errors
```

I've tried searching around a bunch as it seems related to classpath stuff but I just can't seem to grasp it. From the first two errors it appears as though it can't locate my package so I tried

```
javac -cp "/toy_data/" Toy.java
```

although this didn't fix the problem either. I also took a look at the Eclipse .classpath file but that didn't appear too useful.

Toy.java

```
package toy;

import toy.toy_data.Colour;
import toy.toy_data.Phrases;

public class Toy 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Phrases p = new Phrases();
        Colour c = new Colour();

        c.print();
    }
}
```

Colour.java

```
package toy.toy_data;

public class Colour 
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("I am the colour red!");

        Phrases p = new Phrases();
        p.print();
    }
}
```

Phrases.java

```
package toy.toy_data;

public class Phrases 
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello there.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the contents of the Java files as well, there is probably something wrong with the `package` statements. Also does Eclipse actually accept these files? This doesn't really seem to be a question about Eclipse at all.

Comment: @greg-449 Updated with file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javac needs to be able to work out the location of the imported classes. The simplest way to do this is to run the javac command from the `src` directory and use:

```
javac toy/Toy.java
```

Note that this will put the output .class files in the same directories as the source files. To output to the `bin` directory the command would be:

```
javac -d ../bin -sourcepath . toy/Toy.java
```

Generally you don't often use javac directly you either let Eclipse do the compile or use a build tool like [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) or [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) which understand all this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so the problem was that javac couldn't find the 'toy' package before? By compiling from the src folder it can identify it and then the children packages?

Comment: it would be toy.toy_data it could not find - because if you are already in the toy directory it would be trying to look in 'toy/toy/toy_data' - one too many 'toy's